# `redirect_to @article` throws the `NoMethodError in Blog::ArticlesController#create` error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to go through the 'Ruby on Rails Getting Started' tutorial(guides.rubyonrails.org) and I am running into this issue I cannot seem to figure out. I reached the point in the tutorial where I can create an article, but the redirect to see the article immediately after creation does not work and I get an error that says:

```
NoMethodError in Blog::ArticlesController#create
undefined method `article_url' for #<Blog::ArticlesController:0x00007f814841af20>
```

Here is my article controller code:

```
class Blog::ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :category, :text))

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article # <-- This line throws error
  end
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and here is my routes.rb (omitted irrelevant code):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # <-- other get functions here
  get 'blog', to: 'blog#index'
  namespace :blog do
    resources :articles # <-- Suggestions were to make these plural
  end
  root 'about#index'
end
```

The only deviation I have done from the tutorial is that I wanted to place the articles in a name space, as well as 1 extra value to enter in the form(category). The only suggestions for fixing my issue when I searched was to make `resource` into plural but my code already has this and to add `@article = Article.new` into `def new` in the controller but this addition made no difference.

I found a work around that will properly redirect after creating a new article that is the line as follows:

`redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @article.id`

But this doesn't seem like the "Rails Way"(Convention over Configuration), and I really don't understand why the suggested code in the tutorial is not working for me

Comment: Because the route that is created by those two things is different.  So when you put it in a namespace the route changes.  So you have to change the redirect.  Redirecting to @article was likely something like `/article/:id` and you need `/blog/article/:id`, right?  So you have to change the route to redirect to it because the route for `/article/:id` does not exist.  That error explanation really tells you everything about the issue, and you figured out one way to solve it.  So what is the question exactly?

Comment: @RockwellRice The question I meant to ask was why `redirect_to @article` isnt working for me, and you explained it perfectly. I didnt expect the namespace to make a difference as I assumed @article would route it correctly. I have another question though, is the solution/workaround I came up with the best way(or a good way), or is there some other "rails" way that is better?

Comment: The answer below probably feels more inline with what the controller looks like and is what I do with things like this.  Those route helpers just build up.  So when it is in the blog namespace it becomes `blog_article_path(@article)` instead of `article_path(@article)`.  One tip, whenever you have a routing issue run `rake routes` and you can see what you working with and likely solve any issue.  You would have seen the named route like in the answer below

Comment: @RockwellRice ah, everything is now crystal clear. Thank you so much, and thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails-ey way to redirect to the proper route would be to first check in the terminal with `rails routes`.
There you will see if you want to route to `articles#show` under the namespace `blog` that the prefix (first column) is `blog_article`.
You can use this prefix with the `_path` method like so:

```
redirect_to blog_article_path(@article)
```